# How to change the Objective Value Coefficients in Gurobi C++ Model

Tags: c++, gurobi

I built an MIP model that I want to solve multiple times using a set of different objective function coefficients (I realize that warm-start would not be very helpful, I am just trying to avoid model building time).

I built the reusable model by setting the obj coefficient of each variable to `0.0`.

I want to now add the objective coefficients of all the variables to a `std::vector` of values, then optimize the model and set all the objective coefficients to 0 again.

I am currently doing this:

```
auto vars = model.getVars();

auto cols = model.get(GRB_IntAttr_NumVars);

for (int i =0; i < cols; ++i) {
        std::cout << vars[i].get(GRB_StringAttr_VarName) << "\n";
        vars[i].set(GRB_DoubleAttr_Obj, obj_val[i]);
    }


//after doing stuff with the rebuilt-model setting all obj coeffs to 0

for (int i =0; i < cols; ++i) {
        vars[i].set(GRB_DoubleAttr_Obj, 0.0);
    }
delete[] vars;
```

Is there a faster and more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For resetting the objective you can use [setObjective()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/cpp_model_setobjective.html) and just pass `0` as linear expression.

You can also pass all objective coefficients in one call using the [array set methods](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/cpp_model_set.html#cppmethod:GRBModel::set). This should be the fastest way to do this and saves one for loop in your code.

If you are going through all variables anyway when setting a new objective, why do you even bother resetting it to 0 in the first place?

You should also check whether the [multi-objective feature](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/multiple_objectives.html) can be an option for you.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have to reset it. I just would like to have it as an option for debugging. I will take a look at the array set parameters. But I should pass a C style array I suppose. Thanks for the answer

Comment: I had changed it like this `auto vars = model.getVars();
model.set(GRB_DoubleAttr_Obj,vars,obj_vals.data(), 1)`; This did the trick. Maybe I need to ask this as a separate question but is there a faster way to get the indices of the variables which are > 0 without going into a loop?

Comment: I don't think there is a faster way to get the nonzero solution values.